# Cannot access members of a class in the select linq method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

```
static void Main(){

List<Foo> t = new List<Foo>{
            new Foo(){Id=1,Name="A",Value=1},
            new Foo(){Id=2,Name="B",Value=1},
            new Foo(){Id=3,Name="C",Value=1},
            new Foo(){Id=3,Name="D",Value=1}};

var x = t.GroupBy(gp => gp.Id).Select(sel => new Foo {  Id = ,Name=,Value= });

}

public class Foo{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

In the **var x** I want to group all the Foo objects by their ID and get the SUM in the Value field.

The problem is that it seems I cannot access the members/fields of the class in the select method.

Thanks

Comment: Grouping on ID makes me suspect you are actually trying to solve some other problem than the one described. What is it that you need to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `GroupBy` you don't select an `IEnumerable<Foo>` but groups of them. You probably want:

```
var x = t.GroupBy(f => f.Id)
    .Select(grp => new Foo {  
        Id = grp.Key, 
        Name = String.Join(",", grp.Select(f => f.Name)),
        Value = grp.Sum(f => f.Value)
    });
```

I'm using `String.Join` to concenate all names of each ID-group, the values are summed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

var x = t.GroupBy(gp => gp.Name).OrderBy(group => group.Key).Select(group => Tuple.Create(group.Key, group.Count()));